# How to use the same dockerfile for dev and prod

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have 2 Dockerfile, 1 for dev, and 1 for prod:

PROD:

```
FROM golang AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/company/project
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ./release/api .

FROM scratch
EXPOSE 9999
COPY --from=builder /go/src/gitlab.com/company/project/release/api .
CMD ["./api"]
```

and DEV:

```
FROM golang
WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/company/PROJECT
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ./release/api .
CMD ["./release/api"]
```

I would like to merge those two into a single one, as maintaining 2 Dockerfile is a [bad practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

The main difference is that in dev, I work on `golang` image, which is practical, and in prod, I work with `scratch` image, which reduce a lot the size of my binary.

It seems that I can use multiple stages in a Dockerfile, and specify stage name at build time:

```
docker build . --target=builder
```

But If I do this, I don't know how to conditionnaly run my app in the first stage = [ If I am in dev, run the app in the first stage, otherwise, run the app in the second stage]

How should I do it ?

Comment: Just as a question, is there any reason why you would want to have two different images as a base for test and prod? One of the main reasons for using Docker in the first place is that the underlying os and dependencies on the image are the same for each environment.

Comment: well, I wouldn't like to develop on a scratch image, there is nothing in it, not very practical. and I don't want golang image in production because it is too big.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure different dockerfile for development and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440909/how-to-configure-different-dockerfile-for-development-and-production)

Comment: Why not just install the Go toolchain on your host, and use that for development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this? I didn't test it and didn't think through your example deeply, but maybe is somewhere close to what you need/helps you finding out the final solution?

```
FROM golang:alpine AS base
WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/company/project
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ./release/api .

FROM base AS dev
CMD ["./release/api"]

FROM scratch AS prod
EXPOSE 9999
COPY --from=base /go/src/gitlab.com/company/project/release/api .
CMD ["./api"]
```

Depending on the value specified in target `docker build --target=prod` or `docker build --target=dev`, a different image will get built.

Comment: It did the trick ! I didn't use FROM ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}, but I use docker build --target=prod... to build prod, and docker build --target=dev... to build dev

Comment: Your solution is simpler=better than the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440909/how-to-configure-different-dockerfile-for-development-and-production

Comment: let's update it in the answer so it fits to your question :)

Comment: the only issue with this approach, as I used it a few days, is that if I use `docker build --target=prod`, it will also execute the `dev` part, that is useless. It is not a filter, but it gives you the opportunity to run partial Dockerfiles

Comment: why don't you include `CMD ["./release/api"]` in the first image, and rename the "AS base" to "AS dev", then it will stop there, but if prod, will build the next one? `CMD ["./release/api"]` should not affect anything in the first image

Comment: yes, but I am working now in another case of NodeJs, and I install different libs depending on env, so, it works, but build takes more time.